# MarkLogic: Filtering document based on the load_date, when load_date is not range indexed

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have trouble filtering the documents based on the load_date. I want to take a count of documents which are loaded before/after the specified date. I have around 22 million documents in the db. I am not able to used cts:element-range-query as developers have not created range index on "load-date" element. This is stopping me from validating the loaded content from testing perspective.

Please help me with the options.

Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 2):

You could run a [CORB job](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2), which can process this large set of documents with a configurable number of threads to execute a process module for each document URI to determine whether it's `load-date` is before/after the specified date.

The CORB job could select the batch of 22M URIs for documents that have a `load-date` element (or whatever the criteria is for docs to evaluate), and then evaluate whether the `load-date` element has a value that should be counted in the process module that is executed for every one of those document URIs. If the document should be counted, return a value (to keep the file size small, even just the number `1` would be sufficient. Configure the **POST-BATCH-TASK** option to use com.marklogic.developer.corb.PostBatchUpdateFileTask in order to write all of those values to a single file.

Then, when the CORB job completes, you can count the number of lines in the output file:

```
wc -l load-date-count.txt
```

Example [CORB options](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#options):

```
XCC-CONNECTION-URI=xcc://user:password@localhost:8010
URIS-MODULE=uris.xqy|ADHOC
PROCESS-MODULE=process.xqy|ADHOC
THREAD-COUNT=10
POST-BATCH-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.PostBatchUpdateFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-NAME=load-date-count.txt
#
# you might want to enable the DISK-QUEUE, so that the 22M URIs doesn't blow the JVM memory
#DISK-QUEUE=true
```

Example uris.xqy module:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $uris := cts:uris("", (), 
               cts:element-query(xs:QName("load-date"), cts:true-query() ) )
return
  (count($uris), $uris)
```

Example process.xqy module:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare variable $URI as xs:string? external;
if (fn:doc($URI)/*/load-date/xs:date(.) gt xs:date("2017-09-26")) then 1 
else ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Option number 1 is to get the developers to create the range index on load-date -- that is the expected approach to solve this exact problem and should be the preferred solution.

If you can't do that (perhaps this is a one-time query, so there is resistance to adding the index), but the dates are in the proper YYYY-MM-DD format, then you can do string comparisons.

```
fn:count(
  for $item in fn:doc()
  where $item/load_date/fn:string() gt "2015-01-01"
  return $item
)
```

With 22 million documents, this probably won't work. You'll likely get either a timeout or an expanded tree cache full error. If it does work, expect this query to have an impact on how busy your system is. The problem is that you're working without a sorted index, so you need to look at each document. Option 1 is definitely the right way to go if you possibly can.

Comment: Thank you Dave and Hansen.  I am able to achieve  with Xdmp:estimate, cts:directory-query and XS:datetime